# Manga about a girl who is kidnapped by a guy, and transported to another world to find pieces of a sword

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this manga about 9 years ago and I only remember certain parts of this manga. From what I remember is that there's a female lead (high schooler, I think) who gets saved by some guy; she was almost hit by a bus or subway.

She ends up going home and he follows her. They have some kind of fight, because he tries to kidnap her. He has really long hair and ends up cutting it off. The female lead's mom comes in and sees this, then he whisks her away and teleports them back to his time/era. He needs her help to obtain these pieces of a sword which has 11 blades (maybe more, maybe less).

They got on this journey to get the pieces, and another male character enters the storyline and ends up liking the female lead, but I think the male lead likes her as well, so its romance novel too.

I can't remember too much, but I've been looking for this manga a long time! If someone could help me out or knows maybe what the name is that would be much appreciated! thank you in advance.